# How to generate Storyboard dynamically in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a scenario where I have to generate create same StoryBoard Animation in Xaml for a set of data(which I will bind form ViewModel).

```
<Page    
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
 xmlns:miControls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">
<Page.Resources>
        <miControls:ItemsRepeater x:Name="repmeaterTest">
            <miControls:ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="DemoCircle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="50"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04" Value="250"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="DemoCircle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="50"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04" Value="250"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </DataTemplate>
            </miControls:ItemsRepeater.ItemTemplate>
        </miControls:ItemsRepeater>
    </Page.Resources>

<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button x:Name="clikToAnimate" Content="Animate" Click="clikToAnimate_Click" Margin="10"/>
    <Ellipse Name="DemoCircle" Stroke="Purple"  Width="50" Height="50" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="AntiqueWhite"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<int> noOfStoryBoard = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5}; 
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void clikToAnimate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard1.Begin();
    }
}
```

I want to generate StoryBoard dynamically for noOfStoryBoard(ie 5) in xaml
Does anyone have idea kindly share,
Here what i have tried to use items repeater

Comment: Can you provide more details? You already have the storyboard, what's missing? And why can't you use code if necessary?

Comment: Thanks, Peter , There is no issue in coding, But my intention is can we generate storyboard dynamically against a list in XAML only. Because we can handle XAML in Blend. Here what I have tried using Items Repeater please see updated query

Comment: Hello @DharmendraSingh , I did not see a `TextBlock` named `txtCounter` in your code, did you omit this part of the code? In addition, I want to know whether your animation failure refers to an error occur or the animation does not take effect. Can you provide a minimum runable sample so that we can analyze your problem?

Comment: Hi @RichardZhang-MSFT I have updated the whole code. My intent is to somehow dynamically generate Storyboard on XAML for all list items.

Comment: Hello @DharmendraSingh , your code cannot work, because in the `DataTemplate`, it cannot access the external `DemoCircle`, so the property binding will not take effect. Similarly, you cannot directly access the `Storyboard` defined in the `DataTemplate` by name in Code-Behind. `Storyboard` needs to have a clear animation object and target. The `Storyboard` created in the `DataTemplate` can only be applied to the controls inside the `DataTemplate`. If you want to dynamically create the `Storyboard`, it is recommended to create its in Code-Behind.

Comment: Hello, Everyone, I have to achieve this using Storyboard in Code. Might be later Microsoft team will add in Expression Blend As a functionality